# Why does the measurement of the size of a file differ from the size of the string that contains it once buffered?

Tags: c, file, buffer

In order to write the content of a file in a buffer, I first need to know the size of the string to allocate. To do this, I use the following function:

```
long file_length(FILE *fp)
{
    if (fp == NULL) return -1L;
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    const long len = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return len;
}
```

And I use it as follows to store the contents of my file:

```
char *file_content(const char *fname)
{
    assert(access(fname, F_OK) != -1);
    assert(access(fname, R_OK) != -1);

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);

    const long flen = file_length(fp);
    printf("Length of file: %ld\n", flen);

    char *buff = malloc(flen + 1);
    assert(buff != NULL);

    fread(buff, sizeof(char), flen, fp);
    buff[flen + 1] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    return buff;
}
```

And then I test:

```
int main()
{
    char *content = file_content("test.txt");
    printf("Length of buffer: %lld\n", strlen(content));
    free(content);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's `test.txt`:

```
Hello, world!

This is a simple test.

Stackoverflow.
```

My program then displays this:

```
Length of file: 57
Length of buffer: 53
```

As the file has 4 line feeds, I imagine that the result is related to their interpretation according to the different readings that are made (for the position of the file, with `fseek`, and for its buffering, with `fread`). But is it? Or maybe it changes depending on the platform or a reading mode?

If that's the case, so I would like to know how to get the same results, so that I can allocate the exact size of the string directly from my `file_length` function, without having to subtract the number of line feeds the file contains (if it's possible?) in order to be as optimal as possible.

Comment: This may be Windows/DOS CR/LF translation. The file contains CR/LF for each new line but after translating there is only a CR (or LF). That would account for the 4 "missing" bytes.